# npm pkg compiled executable error to run other executable file

Tags: node.js, npm, pkg-config

After compiling a basic code to open a default browser, there's a warning.

[image]

After running , it product this error.

[image]

I am searching on pkg issues about this problem, an currently no solution binding with pkg compiler.

I am sharing my solution to this problem, so may be others save their time.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, after compiling a js code.

let's say you output the executable file to `/folder_name/` .

**copy** `node_modules/opn/xdg-open` to `/folder_name`

and run it like on *nix: `/folder_name $ ./execfile` .